# Has Frank Oz discussed similarities between Yoda and his other roles?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

[Frank Oz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Oz) is the voice actor who plays Yoda, both in The Force Awakens and the rest of the Star Wars films. But he also plays Fozzie Bear, Miss Piggy, Animal, and Sam Eagle, in addition to previous roles as Cookie Monster, Bert, and Grover.

**Has Frank Oz commented on the similarities between Yoda and any of his other characters?**

There are significant similarities in voice inflections between some of these characters. This would be expected from the same actor. But has he commented on personality similarities?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### --------------------------------

**ONGOING RESEARCH**

### --------------------------------

I am interested in this, but I don't have an answer, so I will post things if I find them.

In [this interview](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=w-QD0F2ozD0), Frank Oz says that the thing he likes most about Yoda is that, if there was only one piece of candy left on a plate, Yoda would demand the piece of candy for himself and practically steal it. Frank Oz said this character trait balanced out the Zen Master aspects of Yoda. **So maybe Miss Piggy, Cookie Monster and Animal may be part of Yoda.**  The relevant section starts around 17:45 into the video.

In addition to Frank Oz's comment, [the article at this link discusses George Lucas' intention that Yoda be a blend of Miss Piggy and Kermit The Frog](http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/yoda-kermit-frog-origins_561bf0c8e4b0dbb8000f53c5). In fact, the article contains an embedded video of George Lucas himself saying that Yoda should look and feel like the child of Kermit and Piggy. @RogueJedi said this in a comment below.  Here is a photo of Luke Skywalker with yoda and yoda's hypothetical parents:

[image]

Comment: Can people please post a reason if they downvote a post. +1 to bring balance back to the Force

Comment: This is a very silly question that may simply be "No.", but it's still interesting, and site appropriate. +1

Comment: Well, one similarity is that they are all muppets. :) +1

Comment: The one thing we do know about Frank's relationship with all of these characters is that they were all very accommodating in allowing Frank to get elbow deep into their rears. A gentleman wouldn't discuss such things. (On a more serious note, I've always heard that Frank was eager to portray Yoda because he was a dramatic character, which was a welcome *change* to his typical comic children's roles.)

Comment: I recall Lucas once joked that Yoda was the out-of-wedlock son of Kermit and Ms. Piggy.

Comment: @RogueJedi Funny you said that. I had just found an article and video documenting George Lucas' vision. It meshes with Oz's comment about stealing candy. I added a link at end of OP.

Comment: Yes:  "They all sound like me making a silly voice"  - Frank Oz.

Comment: "And most of them had [Jim Henson's hand up their b%$ts](http://city.sigmalive.com/sites/default/files/kermit_the_frog.jpg)" - Frank Oz

Comment: http://41.media.tumblr.com/da95630159b9f9c2a6a039d46cfd08f2/tumblr_n8ag0zG1MA1ruy9wlo5_1280.jpg

Comment: @WadCheber Most good actors have a few different character templates they adjust for different roles. For example, Chris Hemsworth has the butch guy in Red Dawn and Cabin in the Woods, then the long haired accented Fabio in Thor, Rush, Heart of Sea. Not to mention the goofball in Vacation. Frank Oz doesnt just do one voice, but he might have 3 or 4 templates that overlap across roles.

Comment: @Josh Thank you for ruining people's experience of these characters.

Comment: @WadCheber These characters do not have butts. Your comment on said topic is thus inappropriate. Please delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Oz considers Yoda different from his other roles due to his complexity as a character.

From an interview with *[Orlando Sentinel](http://www.orlandosentinel.com/travel/attractions/the-daily-disney/os-yoda-frank-oz-disney-star-wars-weekends-story.html)* [emphasis mine]:

> **Q:** Your career, of course, is much more than just Yoda. Out of all the characters you’ve performed, what do fans bring up most?
>
> **Oz:** Right now, it’s Yoda. For many, many years it was [Miss] Piggy. She now bubbles quietly under him in pop culture. I’d say now it’s 95 percent Yoda, because people associate him with these extraordinary stories. I love each of them. **They’re all different and all have their own quirks and securities. Grover is easy to do, so I probably enjoy doing him the most. Yoda is a difficult, complex character.**

In an interview with *[The Daily Beast](http://www.thedailybeast.com/star-wars-and-muppets-icon-frank-oz-takes-us-behind-the-puppets)* he talks about how he considered Yoda different from his previous characters, but he ultimately approached the role in the same manner.

> **Oz:** Well Yoda was different, because Yoda was written by George Lucas and Larry Kasdan, so that was a written character with his own design made by somebody else. But what I did with Yoda was pretty much what I did with everybody, which is ask very specific questions and get the Yoda history.